# Fluent NHibernate Denormalized View mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have flat view which I should map to 2 separate C# models

```
class Container
{
   public virtual int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual string Title{get;set;}
   public virtual List<Item> Items{get;set;}
}

class Item
{
   public virtual string Code {get;set;}
   public virtual string Name {get;set;}
}
```

View contains next columns:

---

*ContainerId | Title | Code | Name*

**1 | 'title1' | 'code1' | 'name1'**

**1 | 'title1' | 'code2' | 'name2'**

**2 | 'title2' | 'code1' | 'name1'**

...

How can I do this, to have an ability to make following queries:

```
session.Get<Container>(1)
```

=> `{Id = 1, Title = "title1", Items = [{Code="code1", Name = "name1"}, {Code="code2", Name= "name2"} ]}`

I should somehow map ContainerId as Id, but inside view it is not unique because it is denormalized to contain multiple . Also I should Map some Id inside 'Item' mapping - Item.Code can be used for this.

Thanks!

Comment: So do you have Container and Item tables in the database and a view that displays data from both?

Answer (score 0):

If the two entities you describe are represented in the database as two separate tables and you also have a view that is basically a combination of these two tables I would map them as such.  So you have your entity maps for both `Container` and `Item` and you have an additional "entity" (I call them view objects in my DAL) for the view itself.

Typically I will map database views like this:

```
public class ContainerItemViewMap : ClassMap<ContainerItem>
{
    public ContainerItemViewMap()
    {
        Table("V_CONTAINER_ITEM");
        ReadOnly();
        Not.LazyLoad();
        SchemaAction.None();

        //Location mappings
        Id(x => x.ContainerId, "CONTAINER_ID");
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.Code);
        Map(x => x.Name);

    }
}
```

Also with the retrieval of my view objects I will always use a `Stateless` session because to me it doesn't make sense to use `ISession` here since you aren't going to be doing any CUD (create, update, delete) operations on the data.